# Better way than setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the current function below, but feel like there is a much better way to write the same thing.  I am looking for some insight on the most optimized way to write the same function below and why.

Note this is all inside of `$(function(){});`

```
m = function(){
  $("#id").animate({marginRight : 0}, 'slow', function(){
       $("#id").animate({marginRight : "15px"}, 'slow');
     })
} 
 setInterval(m, 700)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = function(){
  $("#id").animate({marginRight : 0}, 'slow', function(){
       $("#id").animate({marginRight : "15px"}, 'slow',m);
     });
} 
m();
```

It seems, based on what you are doing that you want to toggle an element's motion over time. You can just set the original function `m()` as a callback to be executed when the second, inner animation is done.

Comment: How does this honor the 700ms delay?

Comment: it seems that that was being used to activate the toggling in the first place once the animation was completed. the number is unimportant, unless I am misinterpreting the code

Comment: @Maz you are correct, the number is really unimportant, I would just like to call the function over again once it is complete.

Comment: Also - This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @jnolte - great that you found exactly what you needed, but really if the time of the delay doesn't matter it would be good to say so in the question...

Answer (score 3):

```
(function m(){
    $("#id").animate({marginRight : 0}, 'slow', function(){
        $(this).animate({marginRight : "15px"}, 'slow',function(){
            setTimeout(m,700);
        });
     });
})();
```

EDIT:

it uses setTimeout, however, setTimeout is a better solution than setInterval because it will only queue a new one if the previous one is complete. This will help prevent issues with the RAF that jquery 1.6 currently makes use of.

Answer (score 1):

You can improvise to use `this` inside the first animation callback instead of finding it again. Other than that I dont think any further improvement can be done here.

```
m = function(){
  $("#id").animate({marginRight : 0}, 'slow', function(){
       $(this).animate({marginRight : "15px"}, 'slow');
     })
} 
 setInterval(m, 700);
```